# How can you easily calculate the square root of an unsigned long long in C?

Tags: c, unsigned-long-long-int, long-double

I was looking at another question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808940/x86-assembly-masm-square-root-of-a-64-bit-integer)) where someone was looking for a way to get the square root of a 64 bit integer in x86 assembly.

This turns out to be very simple.  The solution is to convert to a floating point number, calculate the sqrt and then convert back.

I need to do something very similar in C however when I look into equivalents I'm getting a little stuck.  I can only find a sqrt function which takes in doubles.  Doubles do not have the precision to store large 64bit integers without introducing significant rounding error.

Is there a common math library that I can use which has a `long double` sqrt function?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots

Calculating the 64-bit integer square root directly will probably be faster than going through the float conversion.

Comment: Do you want the square root truncated to an integer or rounded to the nearest integer?

Comment: @EricPostpischil for the purpose I have in mind having it truncated is preferable.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I think that's unlikely to happen. x86 has very fast `RSQRTSS`, `VRSQRT14SD`, `VRSQRT28PD` which can produce correct square root result within 2-3 Newton-Raphson iterations. Many other modern architectures have similar instructions. You can even vectorize them if you have to get square root of many values

Comment: @EricPostpischil I've removed your edit. It's contextually incorrect (the other question was agnostic to rounding). The preference I expressed in comments is a mild one and unimportant to the question.  It's perhapse more important that the answer expresses which of the two behaviours it solves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function `sqrtl()`, taking a `long double`, is part of C99.

Note that your compilation platform does not have to implement `long double` as 80-bit extended-precision. It is only required to be as wide as `double`, and Visual Studio implements is as a plain `double`. GCC and Clang do compile `long double` to 80-bit extended-precision on Intel processors.

Comment: That's good to know about Microsoft.  This is for *nix no worries there.

Comment: What do you suggest when `unsigned long long` does not convert precisely to a `long double`?

Comment: @chux: This answer is intended only for platforms in which `unsigned long long` is 64 bits and `long double` has at least 64 bits in the significand.

Answer (score 17):

There is no need for `long double`; the square root can be calculated with `double` (if it is IEEE-754 64-bit binary). The rounding error in converting a 64-bit integer to `double` is nearly irrelevant in this problem.

The rounding error is at most one part in 2<sup>53</sup>. This causes an error in the square root of at most one part in 2<sup>54</sup>. The `sqrt` itself has a rounding error of less than one part in 2<sup>53</sup>, due to rounding the mathematical result to the `double` format. The sum of these errors is tiny; the largest possible square root of a 64-bit integer (rounded to 53 bits) is 2<sup>32</sup>, so an error of three parts in 2<sup>54</sup> is less than .00000072.

For a `uint64_t x`, consider `sqrt(x)`. We know this value is within .00000072 of the exact square root of `x`, but we do not know its direction. If we adjust it to `sqrt(x) - 0x1p-20`, then we know we have a value that is less than, but very close to, the square root of `x`.

Then this code calculates the square root of `x`, truncated to an integer, provided the operations conform to IEEE 754:

```
uint64_t y = sqrt(x) - 0x1p-20;
if (2*y < x - y*y)
    ++y;
```

(`2*y < x - y*y` is equivalent to `(y+1)*(y+1) <= x` except that it avoids wrapping the 64-bit integer if `y+1` is 2<sup>32</sup>.)

Comment: I real like this approach of using double sqrt(double).  I suspect some simplification possible with the rest, but your solution is sweet.

Comment: On the point of precision: in fairness you do have to hack the result of the `sqrt(x)` to get it to give you a correct answer.  Without the additional maths the result will not be one of the two closest integers to the sqrt.  Therefore rounding errors do matter.  The approach of correcting the error after is an interesting one so +1.

Comment: If one wants a rounded square root, how about explicitly checking for values which should give a result of INT_MAX and otherwise testing x against y*(y+1)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the standard library has [`sqrtl()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sqrt) (since C99).

Comment: but `long double` isn't guaranteed to express all `unsigned long long` values exactly

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to calculate sqrt for integers, using divide and conquer should find the result in max 32 iterations:

```
uint64_t mysqrt (uint64_t a)
{
  uint64_t min=0;
  //uint64_t max=1<<32;
  uint64_t max=((uint64_t) 1) << 32; //chux' bugfix
  while(1)
    {
       if (max <= 1 + min)
         return min;           

       uint64_t sqt = min + (max - min)/2;
       uint64_t sq = sqt*sqt;

       if (sq == a) 
         return sqt;

       if (sq > a)
         max = sqt;
       else
         min = sqt;
    }
```

Debugging is left as exercise for the reader.

Comment: Looks good except 1) you need `uint64_t max = ((uint64_t) 1) << 32`, if sizeof(1) <= 4. 2) value returned could be `uint32_t`.

Comment: instead of `(uint64_t) 1` use 1ULL or `(UINT64_C)1`

Answer (score 2):

Here we collect several observations in order to arrive to a solution:

1. In standard C >= 1999, it is garanted that non-netative integers have a representation in bits as one would expected for any base-2 number.
   ----> Hence, we can trust in bit manipulation of this type of numbers.
2. If `x` is a unsigned integer type, tnen `x >> 1 == x / 2` and `x << 1 == x * 2`.
   (!) But: It is very probable that bit operations shall be done faster than their arithmetical counterparts.
3. `sqrt(x)` is mathematically equivalent to `exp(log(x)/2.0)`.
4. If we consider truncated logarithms and base-2 exponential for integers, we could obtain a fair estimate: `IntExp2( IntLog2(x) / 2) "==" IntSqrtDn(x)`, where `"="` is informal notation meaning *almost equatl to* (in the sense of a good approximation).
5. If we write `IntExp2( IntLog2(x) / 2 + 1) "==" IntSqrtUp(x)`, we obtain an "above" approximation for the integer square root.
6. The approximations obtained in (4.) and (5.) are a little rough (they enclose the true value of sqrt(x) between two consecutive powers of 2), but they could be a very well starting point for any algorithm that searchs for the square roor of `x`.
7. The **Newton algorithm** for square root could be work well for integers, if we have a good first approximation to the real solution.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root

The final algorithm needs some mathematical comprobations to be plenty sure that always work properly, but I will not do it right now... I will show you the final program, instead:

```
    #include <stdio.h>   /* For printf()...  */
    #include <stdint.h>  /* For uintmax_t... */
    #include <math.h>    /* For sqrt() ....  */

    int IntLog2(uintmax_t n) {
        if (n == 0) return -1; /* Error */
        int L;
        for (L = 0; n >>= 1; L++)
           ;
        return L; /* It takes < 64 steps for long long */
    }

    uintmax_t IntExp2(int n) {
        if (n < 0)
           return 0; /* Error */            
        uintmax_t E;
        for (E = 1; n-- > 0; E <<= 1)
            ;
        return E; /* It takes < 64 steps for long long */
    }

    uintmax_t IntSqrtDn(uintmax_t n) { return IntExp2(IntLog2(n) / 2); }

    uintmax_t IntSqrtUp(uintmax_t n) { return IntExp2(IntLog2(n) / 2 + 1); }

    int main(void) {
        uintmax_t N = 947612934;  /* Try here your number! */

        uintmax_t sqrtn  = IntSqrtDn(N),  /* 1st approx. to sqrt(N) by below */
                  sqrtn0 = IntSqrtUp(N);  /* 1st approx. to sqrt(N) by above */

        /* The following means while( abs(sqrt-sqrt0) > 1) { stuff... } */
        /* However, we take care of subtractions on unsigned arithmetic, just in case... */
        while ( (sqrtn > sqrtn0 + 1) ||  (sqrtn0 > sqrtn+1) )
           sqrtn0 = sqrtn, sqrtn = (sqrtn0  + N/sqrtn0) / 2; /* Newton iteration */

        printf("N==%llu, sqrt(N)==%g, IntSqrtDn(N)==%llu, IntSqrtUp(N)==%llu, sqrtn==%llu, sqrtn*sqrtn==%llu\n\n",  
                N,            sqrt(N),       IntSqrtDn(N),       IntSqrtUp(N),      sqrtn,       sqrtn*sqrtn);

        return 0;
    }
```

The last value stored in `sqrtn` is the integer square root of `N`.
The last line of the program just shows all the values, with comprobation purposes.
So, you can try different values of `N`and see what happens.

If we add a counter inside the while-loop, we'll see that no more than a few iterations happen.

**Remark:** It is necessary to verify that the condition `abs(sqrtn-sqrtn0)<=1` is always achieved when working in the integer-number setting. If not, we shall have to fix the algorithm.

**Remark2:** In the initialization sentences, observe that `sqrtn0 == sqrtn * 2 == sqrtn << 1`. This avoids us some calculations.

Answer (score 0):

```
// sqrt_i64 returns the integer square root of v.
int64_t sqrt_i64(int64_t v) {
    uint64_t q = 0, b = 1, r = v;
    for( b <<= 62; b > 0 && b > r; b >>= 2);
    while( b > 0 ) {
        uint64_t t = q + b;
        q >>= 1;           
        if( r >= t ) {     
            r -= t;        
            q += b;        
        }
        b >>= 2;
    }
    return q;
}
```

The for loop may be optimized by using the `clz` machine code instruction.