# C-greatest prime factor of a given number

Tags: c, execution-time

I have written the following code to compute the greatest prime factor of a number supplied 
through standard input but it is taking ages to execute.How can i reduce the execution time of the program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_prime(unsigned long long num)
{
    if (num == 0 || num == 1)
        return false;
    if (num == 2)
        return true;
    for (unsigned long long j = 2; j < num; j++)
        if(num%j==0)
            return false;

    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long n,i;
    printf("enter the number: ");
    scanf("%llu",&n);
    for(i=n-1;i>1;i--)
        if((is_prime(i)) && n%i==0)
            break;
    printf("%llu\n",i);

    return 0;
}
```

Number in the input is  600851475143.

Comment: In `is-prime`, apart from checking 2, you only need check the odd numbers up to the square root of `num`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1538653/2065121) for some useful information.

Comment: @RogerRowland please elaborate on why upto square root of num.

Comment: If a number has one factor greater than its square root, it *must* also have a corresponding factor *less* than the square root. So you only need to check as far as the square root in order to find the lower of those factors.

Comment: you could also memoize the prime numbers. but any decent developer would start with googling for fast prime testing...

Comment: 600851400151  take a look at http://markknowsnothing.com/cgi-bin/primes.php

Comment: `for(unsigned long long j = 2;` is inefficient, since you already check for 2 earlier. Use `for(unsigned long long j = 3;` instead.

Comment: Oh no, O(1) extra work.

Comment: Divide out the numbers as you find them. That keeps the search small. Also, you don't really care if the factor is prime until the very end, so don't test primality. That is more expensive than the division. And if you test smaller numbers first, then you already know the first factor you find is prime. (If it weren't, you would have found one of the factors first.) A hard-coded table of the first million prime numbers will also help.

Comment: Once you're looking at the odd numbers in `is_prime()`, you can increment by 2 rather than one.  When you find a prime factor, you can divide the given number by that prime factor (as often as possible) without altering the answer but reducing the amount of work needed.  You could also consider finding factors of the number and then checking whether the factor is prime, rather than checking whether a possible factor is prime before checking whether it is a divisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have fun...one function for all prime factors, one for maximum prime factor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned long long u64_t;

static size_t prime_factors(u64_t value, u64_t *array)
{
    size_t n_factors = 0;
    u64_t n = value;
    u64_t i;

    while (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        n /= 2;
        //printf("Factor: %llu (n = %llu)\n", 2ULL, n);
        array[n_factors++] = 2;
    }

    while (n % 3 == 0)
    {
        n /= 3;
        //printf("Factor: %llu (n = %llu)\n", 3ULL, n);
        array[n_factors++] = 3;
    }

    for (i = 6; (i - 1) * (i - 1) <= n; i += 6)
    {   
        while (n % (i-1) == 0)
        {
            n /= (i-1);
            //printf("Factor: %llu (n = %llu)\n", (i-1), n);
            array[n_factors++] = (i-1);
        }
        while (n % (i+1) == 0)
        {
            n /= (i+1);
            //printf("Factor: %llu (n = %llu)\n", (i+1), n);
            array[n_factors++] = (i+1);
        }
    }
    if (n != 1)
        array[n_factors++] = n;

    return n_factors;
}

static u64_t max_prime_factor(u64_t value)
{
    u64_t n = value;
    u64_t i;
    u64_t max = n;

    while (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        n /= 2;
        //printf("Factor: %llu (n = %llu)\n", 2ULL, n);
        max = 2;
    }

    while (n % 3 == 0)
    {
        n /= 3;
        //printf("Factor: %llu (n = %llu)\n", 3ULL, n);
        max = 3;
    }

    for (i = 6; (i - 1) * (i - 1) <= n; i += 6)
    {   
        while (n % (i-1) == 0)
        {
            n /= (i-1);
            //printf("Factor: %llu (n = %llu)\n", (i-1), n);
            max = (i-1);
        }
        while (n % (i+1) == 0)
        {
            n /= (i+1);
            //printf("Factor: %llu (n = %llu)\n", (i+1), n);
            max = (i+1);
        }
    }
    //printf("Max Factor = %llu\n", (n == 1) ? max : n);

    return (n == 1) ? max : n;
}

static void print_factors(u64_t value, size_t n_factors, u64_t *factors)
{
    printf("%20llu:", value);
    int len = 21;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_factors; i++)
    {
        if (len == 0)
            len = printf("%.21s", "");
        len += printf(" %llu", factors[i]);
        if (len >= 60)
        {
            putchar('\n');
            len = 0;
        }
    }
    if (len > 0)
        putchar('\n');
}

void builtin_tests(void)
{
    u64_t tests[] =
    {
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
        19, 20, 25, 49, 63, 69, 71, 73, 825, 829, 1000, 6857, 73112,
        731122, 7311229, 73112293, 731122935, 7311229357, 73112293571,
        600851475143, 731122935711, 7311229357111,
        18446744073709551610ULL, 18446744073709551611ULL,
        18446744073709551612ULL, 18446744073709551613ULL,
        18446744073709551614ULL, 18446744073709551615ULL,
    };
    u64_t factors[64];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(tests)/sizeof(tests[0]); i++)
    {
        u64_t max = max_prime_factor(tests[i]);
        printf("%20llu -> Max Prime Factor = %llu\n", tests[i], max);
        size_t n_factors = prime_factors(tests[i], factors);
        print_factors(tests[i], n_factors, factors);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc == 1)
        builtin_tests();
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            u64_t factors[64];
            u64_t value = strtoull(argv[i], 0, 0);
            u64_t max = max_prime_factor(value);
            printf("%20llu -> Max Prime Factor = %llu\n", value, max);
            size_t n_factors = prime_factors(value, factors);
            print_factors(value, n_factors, factors);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Results

```
                   1 -> Max Prime Factor = 1
                   1:
                   2 -> Max Prime Factor = 2
                   2: 2
                   3 -> Max Prime Factor = 3
                   3: 3
                   4 -> Max Prime Factor = 2
                   4: 2 2
                   5 -> Max Prime Factor = 5
                   5: 5
                   6 -> Max Prime Factor = 3
                   6: 2 3
                   7 -> Max Prime Factor = 7
                   7: 7
                   8 -> Max Prime Factor = 2
                   8: 2 2 2
                   9 -> Max Prime Factor = 3
                   9: 3 3
                  10 -> Max Prime Factor = 5
                  10: 2 5
                  11 -> Max Prime Factor = 11
                  11: 11
                  12 -> Max Prime Factor = 3
                  12: 2 2 3
                  13 -> Max Prime Factor = 13
                  13: 13
                  14 -> Max Prime Factor = 7
                  14: 2 7
                  15 -> Max Prime Factor = 5
                  15: 3 5
                  16 -> Max Prime Factor = 2
                  16: 2 2 2 2
                  17 -> Max Prime Factor = 17
                  17: 17
                  18 -> Max Prime Factor = 3
                  18: 2 3 3
                  19 -> Max Prime Factor = 19
                  19: 19
                  20 -> Max Prime Factor = 5
                  20: 2 2 5
                  25 -> Max Prime Factor = 5
                  25: 5 5
                  49 -> Max Prime Factor = 7
                  49: 7 7
                  63 -> Max Prime Factor = 7
                  63: 3 3 7
                  69 -> Max Prime Factor = 23
                  69: 3 23
                  71 -> Max Prime Factor = 71
                  71: 71
                  73 -> Max Prime Factor = 73
                  73: 73
                 825 -> Max Prime Factor = 11
                 825: 3 5 5 11
                 829 -> Max Prime Factor = 829
                 829: 829
                1000 -> Max Prime Factor = 5
                1000: 2 2 2 5 5 5
                6857 -> Max Prime Factor = 6857
                6857: 6857
               73112 -> Max Prime Factor = 37
               73112: 2 2 2 13 19 37
              731122 -> Max Prime Factor = 52223
              731122: 2 7 52223
             7311229 -> Max Prime Factor = 24953
             7311229: 293 24953
            73112293 -> Max Prime Factor = 880871
            73112293: 83 880871
           731122935 -> Max Prime Factor = 89107
           731122935: 3 5 547 89107
          7311229357 -> Max Prime Factor = 7311229357
          7311229357: 7311229357
         73112293571 -> Max Prime Factor = 8058227
         73112293571: 43 211 8058227
        600851475143 -> Max Prime Factor = 6857
        600851475143: 71 839 1471 6857
        731122935711 -> Max Prime Factor = 4973625413
        731122935711: 3 7 7 4973625413
       7311229357111 -> Max Prime Factor = 12939061
       7311229357111: 547 1033 12939061
18446744073709551610 -> Max Prime Factor = 1504703107
18446744073709551610: 2 5 23 53301701 1504703107
18446744073709551611 -> Max Prime Factor = 287630261
18446744073709551611: 11 59 98818999 287630261
18446744073709551612 -> Max Prime Factor = 2147483647
18446744073709551612: 2 2 3 715827883 2147483647
18446744073709551613 -> Max Prime Factor = 364870227143809
18446744073709551613: 13 3889 364870227143809
18446744073709551614 -> Max Prime Factor = 649657
18446744073709551614: 2 7 7 73 127 337 92737 649657
18446744073709551615 -> Max Prime Factor = 6700417
18446744073709551615: 3 5 17 257 641 65537 6700417
```

Answer (score 3):

```
bool is_prime(unsigned long long num)
{
    if (num <  2) return false;      /* Reject border cases */

    if (num == 2) return true;       /* Accept the largest even prime */

    if ((num & (~1)) == num) return false;  /* Reject all other evens */

    unsigned long long limit = sqrt(num) + 1;  /* Limit the range of the search */

    for (unsigned long long j = 3; j < limit; j += 2)  /* Loop through odds only */
        if(num % j==0)
            return false;           /* Reject factors */

    return true;                    /* No factors, hence it is prime */

}
```

Comment: I'm not near a compiler to test.  sqrt(num) into a long long is a questionable way to do it.

Comment: `j < limit` should be `j <= limit`. For example, what if I choose num=9? The loop won't even run. Same with num=25,49,81,...

Comment: @chrono  I added one to the limit instead.  My OCD doesn't like <= in for loops

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499492/how-can-you-easily-calculate-the-square-root-of-an-unsigned-long-long-in-c?lq=1              As important as 64 bit integers are, there really ought to be a function to do the job without the conversion to and from doubles

Comment: Indeed there ought to be, but it isn't difficult to do. The code is out there too. For example, [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Digit-by-digit_calculation).

Comment: @EvilTeach, Your test for rejecting "all other evens" is incorrect.  s/b: if ((num&1)==0) return false;   Your test if ((num&1)==num) only succeeds if num is 0 or 1.

Comment: Humm... I was meaning to toss away the 1 bit.   That doesn't do it does it.   Nice catch.  Humm.. what about ~1.  That ought to be better.  7 = 111.  111 & 110 yields 110.   111 != 110. 010 & 110 yields 010.  010==010 Ya. it's better

Comment: You didn't like if((num&1)==0)?  Tests against zero are fast.

Answer (score 1):

keeping the same logic you can reduce time by executing loop till sqrt(num) only.
because if it is not prime, there would be at least one divisor which is less then sqrt(num).

Let's take num is not prime. so for some 1< a < num, a*b = num.

so either a or b should be less than sqrt(num).

Hence your code be for is_prime should be changed to the one as follows

```
bool is_prime(unsigned long long num)
{
    if (num == 0 || num == 1)
        return false;
    if (num == 2)
        return true;
    long long root_num = sqrt(num);
    for (unsigned long long j = 2; j < root_num; j++)
        if(num%j==0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Now if you want to change your logic, then there is an algorithm called sieve method which finds all prime numbers which are less than given number. check this out [Sieve Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: Surely `for (unsigned long long j = 3; j < root_num; j+=2)` would be better? (2 is already tested and remaining prime factors must be odd).

Comment: Hey Roger,
I said it would be better keeping the same logic in is_prime function.
in is_prime() we are not finding prime factors. We are finding a number's divisors, right ?
skipping even numbers for testing is_prime is different thing.

Comment: If you're finding a number's divisors, and you already found that 2 is *not* one of them, then there is no point to check any other even numbers because if an even number is a divisor, then 2 will also be a divisor. So you can cut the size of the loop in half by only checking for odd divisors.

Comment: Sir, you are correct.
But all I am saying is, even if you do j+=2 that does not make any difference in complexity.
it would be O(num/2). i.e. still O(num), which is same as the original code.
of course it would be a bit efficient but not by complexity.
That is why i didn't ask him to do j += 2;
Thanks.

Comment: Ok but he was asking how to reduce the execution time, which is why my comment is relevant. It's a small point and others have taken account of it in their answers, so I just thought you'd like to improve yours too, it's no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

The if statement in the loop in main() should check n%i==0 first so that non-factors are not checked for primeness.  This alone makes the program over 200 times faster on all the numbers from 1 to 2000 on a simple test case I ran on a modern Intel CPU.  The mod below just to main() (I broke it out into a function returning the largest prime factor) improves the speed significantly more.  I also consider the number itself as a possible factor (not done in the original).

```
unsigned long long largest_prime_factor(unsigned long long n)

    {
    unsigned long long i,sqrtn,maxprime;

    if (is_prime(n))
        return(n);
    sqrtn=(unsigned long long)sqrt((double)n);
    maxprime=1;
    for (i=2;i<=sqrtn;i++)
        {
        if (n%i==0)
            {
            unsigned long long f;

            f=n/i;
            if (is_prime(f))
                return(f);
            if (is_prime(i))
                maxprime=i;
            }
        }
    return(maxprime);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to start for loop from square root of number to 3,
again you can skip even numbers.

so that you can get answer within small time..