# Check if a number is a perfect square in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors, sqrt, math.h

**Task:**

In an array of N elements (N < 20) of the unsigned long long type
find the maximal full square and print its index (starting from zero).
If there are no full squares, print -1.
If there is more than one maximal square, print the index of the first one.

Input data: standard input stream, where
N is written on the first line
on the second line the array elements with a space.

Output data: a number in a standard output stream

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  
    unsigned short int n;
    unsigned long long mass[20];
    unsigned long long max = 0;
    int max_index = -1;
    
    scanf("%hu", &n);

    if (n >= 20) {

      do{
        
        scanf("%hu", &n);
        
      }while(n >= 20);
      
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%llu", &mass[i]);

        long double root = (long double) sqrt(mass[i]);
        if (root * root == mass[i]) {

            if (mass[i] > max) {
                max = mass[i];
                max_index = i;
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf("%d\n", max_index);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have this error while compiling

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfYmw.png)

I tried to use different types of data but it was useless.

Comment: C doesn't have overloaded functions.

Comment: Compiler output is text. Don't post pictures of text, post text as properly formatted text.

Comment: "_more than one maximal square_" ??? How would this be possible?

Comment: @Fe2O3 i think it means: if maximal square found twice, e.g., mass = {1, 2, 3, **4**, **4**}

Comment: Your [code](https://godbolt.org/z/3dPvz35nE) is fine, at least it compiles without warnings or errors. Probably your project is not properly configured.

Comment: How is "perfect square" from the title related to "maximum square" from the question body?

Comment: @rvevau My bad... "output the index of the first..." Overlooked that...

Comment: Is your question about "perfect" or what ever squares, or about your program not compiling?

Comment: @Gerhardh I think the question is rather about the code not compiling.

Comment: Should you be rounding the `sqrt` and assigning to an integer type before squaring?

Comment: @WeatherVane i think it is not necessary

Comment: @rvevau To make up for that: I'd suggest making a copy of the array, sorting in descending order, then start testing each value (in descending order). If a perfect square value is found it will be the "maximal", then search the original array from the beginning for that value. No sense wasting time calculating roots in the original sequence when the best target might appear far, far later in the array... (can also skip over duplicates just by remembering the previous value...)

Comment: @Fe2O3 sounds good, i will try it now

Comment: If you don't round the floating point square root, you'll get loads of false positives.

Comment: @Fe2O3 For maximally 20 elements all that coding effort (actually introducing an `O(n*log(n))` algorithm where the current approach is linear) simply doesn't appear worth it. I'd go with the simpler linear approach – where actually the array could be dropped *entirely*...

Comment: Using floats or doubles to calculate the square roots of long longs is not reliable.

Comment: `x(); if(condition) { do { x(); } while(condition /*exactly the same one!*/); }` is fully equivalent to just having the loop without the surrounding if. Apart from: I wouldn't loop at all, but return immediately if the condition is not met; otherwise you'd start reading the array values interpreting them as array size until one of them *accidentally* fits the condition – which might never occur (imagine 21 followed by 21 times 1000).

Comment: @Aconcagua While I see your point about code bulk, I wonder if `sqrt()` is as fast as all that these days... Not back in my day, to be sure!! (And, the target system may be an MCU without serious math circuitry...)

Comment: Just to explain what the error even _means_: It says there exist three variations of `sqrt`, one that takes a `float`, one that takes a `double` and one that takes a `long double`. Normally the right one would be selected based on the type of the argument you pass. However, you passed a `long long`, which is neither of those. That in itself also wouldn't be a problem if there would be only one compatible type to convert to, because then the conversion could happen automatically, but in this case there are three possibilities and the compiler doesn't know what type to convert it to.

Comment: @Fe2O3 MCU with standard input streams? And such an actually meaningless problem? Pretty unlikely, isn't it? As inefficient as `sqrt` might be, for just 20 samples we won't even notice any difference. Apart from: In worst case (only smallest member is square or none contained at all) you'd still iterate the entire array...

Comment: @CherryDT Oh, seems to be a tag mismatch: `C` doesn't have overloads, so file apparently compiled as C++...

Comment: @CherryDT the thing is that there is no error in the tag, the programme is really written in c, as required, apparently the teacher has problems with the compiler

Comment: Just to put this on record, `n%10` can be quickly determined, AND no square ends with the decimal digit 2, 3, 7 or 8. Depending on the speed of calculating a square root, one might eliminate 40% of that effort _pre-screening_ by investing to check the mod10 "residue" of the original `n`.

Comment: [Related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer?rq=2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least these issues:

**Wrong compiler**

Error message indicates OP is using a C++ compiler when a C compiler  should be used for C code.  Function overloading (part of C++) is not a standard feature of C.

**Loss of precision**

`sqrt(mass[i])` can loses precision.  `unsigned long long` is at least a 64-bit type and converting that to `double` (to preform the square root) can lose needed precision.  Floating point math introduces rounding issues too that can lead to incorrect results for this integer problem.  Better to use integer math than floating-point math for an integer problem.

Similar problems with `root * root == mass[i]`

Consider forming a `unsigned long long isqrt_ull(unsigned long long x)` to find the square root.

Sample:

```
// Recursive version.
unsigned long long isqrt_ull(unsigned long long x) {
  if (x < 2) {
    return x;
  }
  unsigned long long s = isqrt_ull(x >> 2) << 1;
  unsigned long long t = s + 1;
  return (t > x / t) ? s : t;
}
```

**Corner case: 0**

If the array values are all 0, code reports -1 as `mass[i] > max` is never true.  Better as `mass[i] > max || max_index == -1`

---

Other minor issues

- No need to test a new candidate for perfect square-ness unless it is greater than the prior max.
- Avoid type proliferation: Use `int` for reading the array size in this learner's exercise.
- Check return value of `scanf()` to know if input succeeded.
- `isqrt_ull()` is not a highly efficient integer square root routine.  It is just there as a simple placeholder that does not suffer floating point issues yet handles `unsigned long long`.

Comment: I personally would rather recommend `unsigned int` for the array size, this avoids having to test for negative values...

Comment: @Aconcagua I'd agree `unsigned` is better than `unsigned short` here. Yet with `unsigned` we have trouble of properly detecting negative input, input overflow, printing -1, ...  (`int` has some of these issues too.)  IAC, robust input validation is another rabbit hole.

Comment: Negative values would be mapped to far too large values (and we don't differentiate if below lower bound or above upper bound), so we are safe at this point – and the actually possible `-1` is only stored at yet another variable (and that one *is* signed), so no problem either. Apart from an unsigned integer, no matter which size, reflects the purpose of the variable better: size/length of an array, so negative values are entirely meaningless.

Comment: [`sqrt` can be used to compute the square root of a 64-bit integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499492/how-can-you-easily-calculate-the-square-root-of-an-unsigned-long-long-in-c/18501209#18501209) using `uint64_t y = sqrt(x) - 0x1p-20; if (2*y < x - y*y) ++y;`. Essentially, the square root of a 64-bit number is less than 2^32, and the relative rounding errors of a `double` are on the order of 2^−53, so they are tiny for the square root and could only ever push it over one integer boundary.

Comment: It may be that if a 64-bit integer is a perfect square, then rounding it to a `double` and taking the square root with a correctly rounded `sqrt` must produce the square root, so the only test needed is `uint64_t y = sqrt(x); if (y*y == x)…`, but I have not done the analysis to prove that. If it does not, I suspect something like `unt64_t y = sqrt(x) + 0x1p-20; if (y*y == x)…` would suffice.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes that [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499492/how-can-you-easily-calculate-the-square-root-of-an-unsigned-long-long-in-c/18501209#18501209) is a quite good and deserves consideration, at least until `unsigned long long` is 128-bit.  BITD `unsigned long` was _always_ 32-bit.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I noticed a sign change in [`unt64_t y = sqrt(x) + 0x1p-20;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77272144/check-if-a-number-is-a-perfect-square-in-c/77272313?noredirect=1#comment136227197_77272313).  Was that intended?  `unt64_t y = sqrt((uint64_t)-1) + 0x1p-20;` reports 0x1_0000_0000.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Re “sign change”: Yes, the linked problem was to find the floor of the square root, and subtracting 0x1p-20 before converting to integer usually gave the correct answer, with a correction rarely required. In this case, where we want to test whether a number is a perfect square, adding 0x1p-20 will correct cases for perfect squares that were incorrectly rounded low, and we do not care about pushing something up because if the true square root was x.99999…something, the input number is not a perfect square and will not pass the test regardless…

Comment: … Getting 2^32 for input of 2^64−1 is fine because multiplying it by itself will wrap to produce zero, which will compare unequal to 2^64−1, thus correctly reporting 2^64−1 is not a perfect square. More generally, we never care what the result `x` of “find approximate square root” is for a non-square `y` except we do not want it to be so far off that `x*x` wraps to produce `y`, since there is no `uint64_t` value `x` for which `x*x` will equal the non-square `y` except for cases where it wraps. We primarily care that “find approximate square root” finds the exact square root for squares.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Thanks for that info.  I suppose an exhaustive test of all values (with `float/unint32_t` rather than `double/uint64_t`) may serve as supporting evidence.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are on an older version of the Microsoft compiler.  I can't repro your compiler error in the version I have.

But you could and should probably change this:

```
    long double root = (long double) sqrt(mass[i]);
    if (root * root == mass[i]) {
```

To this:

```
    double value = (double)mass[i];
    double root = sqrt(value);
    if (root * root == value) {
```

The conversion back to long double doesn't buy you anything. And the explicit cast of `mass[i]` form unsigned long long to double probably fixes your compiler error.

**update**

It would probably better if you avoided floating point altogether. Some compilers and runtimes have inherent precision issues with their implementation of the sqrt function. Most of the time it works as expected for whole numbers, but why take the chance? Let's introduce a worthy square root algorithm for unsigned long long integers. It's pretty much just a binary search.

```
unsigned long long squareRoot(unsigned long long value) {

    // To prevent overflow, take advangage of the fact that sizeof(result) <= sizeof(value)/2
    // This likely assumes two's complement machine
    const unsigned long long max_value = (unsigned long long)(-1);
    const unsigned long long max_square_root = max_value >> (4 * sizeof(value));

    unsigned long long low = 0;
    unsigned long long high = (value > max_square_root) ? max_square_root : (value / 2);
    unsigned long long mid = value / 2;

    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        unsigned long long midSquared = mid * mid;
        if (midSquared == value) {
            return mid;
        }
        if (midSquared < value) {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
    }

    // return the value closest to the actual square root without going over
    if (mid * mid > value) {
        mid--;
    }
    return mid;
}
```

Then your main loop is simply:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%llu", &mass[i]);

    unsigned long long root = squareRoot(mass[i]);
    if (root * root == mass[i]) {
        if (mass[i] > max) {
            max = mass[i];
            max_index = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the advice

Comment: `double` has less precision bits (usually, at least) than `unsigned long long` – are there any square numbers that aren't squares any more after cutting off some LSB? I personally would feel safer using `long double` and `sqrtl` – at least if it has higher precision than `double`, of course, which – unfortunately(?) – is not guaranteed, I know...

Comment: Simpler to think about smaller numbers. Think about `unsigned short` (0-65535)... Seeking `sqrt(64000)` leads to 32000 * 32000... That product won't fit into an `unsigned short`... (I only know this because I was going to post the same idea (binary search aka _successive approximation_) but stopped when I realised the problem.)

Comment: You could try: `high = value > ULONG_MAX ? ULONG_MAX : value;` Again, thinking of the easier 2 byte version `unsigned short high = value > 255 ? 255 : value;` At least this won't blow up on the first iteration...

Comment: @Fe2O3 - I agree with you.  It's not the most efficient algorithm.  But the OP seems to be in learning mode, so probably best to suggest readable solutions over optimal ones.

Comment: All well and good. Please refer to my earlier comment, though. The overflow resulting from multiplication may lead the OP to the dark side (where erroneous results are not noticed.)

Comment: `mid * mid` overflows when `value` islarge.

Comment: Good call. fixed.